# Elements getting double added to dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, boolean

I am trying to write code that will take data in this format

data example:

```
[['12319825', '39274', {'pH': 8.1}], ['12319825', '39610', {'pH': 7.27}],
['12319825', '39638', {'pH': 7.87, 'Escherichia coli': 25.0}],
['12319825', '39770', {'pH': 7.47, 'Escherichia coli': 27.0}],
['12319825', '39967', {'pH': 8.36}], ['12319825', '39972', {'pH': 8.42}],
['12319825', '39987', {'pH': 8.12, 'Escherichia coli': 8.0}],
['12319825', '40014', {'pH': 8.12}], ['12319825', '40329',{'pH': 8.45}], 
['12319825', '40658', {'pH': 8.35, 'Escherichia coli': 6.3}],
['12319825', '40686', {'pH': 8.17}], 
['12319825', '40714', {'pH': 8.13}], ['12319825', '40732', {'pH': 8.4}],
['12319825', '40809', {'pH': 8.42}], 
['12319825', '40827', {'pH': 8.46}], 
['12319825', '41043', {'pH': 8.42, 'Escherichia coli': 170.0}],
['12319825', '41071', {'pH': 8.24, 'Escherichia coli': 92.0}],
['12319825', '41080', {'pH': 8.4}], 
['12319825', '41101', {'pH': 8.36, 'Escherichia coli': 560.0}], ['12319825', '41134', {'pH': 8.67}]]
```

and will return the a dictionary where the key is the pollutant (in this case, either pH or Escherichia coli) and the value is what I am calling DateList. Date list will be a list tuples for each data point with the format (date, T/F). The boolean will be true if the value is outside of a given range, or over a given value (depending on the type of criteria)

```
rangeCriteria={'pH':(5.0,9.0)}
convCriteria={'Echerichia coli':320)
```

Now, when I run this code, each dictionary has values for both the

```
def testLocationForConv(DataFromLocation): 
#checks if a pollutant is outside of acceptable values. 
#A dictionary is created where each pollutant has a cooresponding list of tuples
#with the date and a corresponding boolean to say if it is in or out of
#the criteria (true if out false if in) 
#It handles when the criteria is a minimum or range rather than a
#maximum

dateList=[]
impairedList=[]
overDict=dict()
for date in DataFromLocation:
    for pollutant in date[2]:
        if pollutant in conventionalCriteriaList: 
            dateList.append((date[1],date[2][pollutant]>convCriteria[pollutant]))
            overDict[pollutant]=dateList
        if pollutant in rangeCriteria:
            overDict[pollutant]=dateList
            dateList.append((date[1], (not (float(date[2][pollutant])>rangeCriteria[pollutant][0] and float(date[2][pollutant])<rangeCriteria[pollutant][1])) ))
        #if pollutant in minCriteriaList:
         #   overDict[pollutant]=dateList
          #  dateList.append((date[1],date[2][pollutant]<minCriteria[pollutant])

        else:
           pass  
print overDict
```

Now, data points for both pollutants are added to the dictionary, giving the following result.

```
{'pH': [('39274', False), ('39610', False), ('39638', False), 
('39638', False), ('39770', False), ('39770', False), ('39967', False),
('39972', False), ('39987', False), ('39987', False), ('40014', False),
('40329', False), ('40658', False), ('40658', False), ('40686', False),
('40714', False), ('40732', False), ('40809', False), ('40827', False),
('41043', False), ('41043', False), ('41071', False), ('41071', False),
('41080', False), ('41101', False), ('41101', True), ('41134', False)], 
'Escherichia coli': [('39274', False), ('39610', False), ('39638', False), 
('39638', False), ('39770', False), ('39770', False), ('39967', False),
('39972', False), ('39987', False), ('39987', False), ('40014', False),
('40329', False), ('40658', False), ('40658', False), ('40686', False),
('40714', False), ('40732', False), ('40809', False), ('40827', False),
('41043', False), ('41043', False), ('41071', False), ('41071', False),
('41080', False), ('41101', False), ('41101', True), ('41134', False)]}
```

Now that I type out this question, I realize that the issue is that I am iterating for dates, then pollutants, but I want a list that compiles dates, but is separate for pollutants. How would I make such a list and add it to the dictionary?

Comment: After rereading your post twice, I figured out mostly what you're asking for, but it would be a lot simpler and I wouldn't be hurting my head as much if you would just post an example of what output you want. You also didn't post your full code -- for instance, what is `conventionalCriteriaList`?

Comment: So, the first item in the list is always thrown away?

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to do `overDict[pollutant]=dateList` every time... it's the same exact list. Which is why in your dictionary the values are exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

I would take a step back and think about your approach. You are making things harder for yourself. First, the data:

```
In [3]: data = [['12319825', '39274', {'pH': 8.1}], ['12319825', '39610', {'pH':
   ...:  7.27}],
   ...: ['12319825', '39638', {'pH': 7.87, 'Escherichia coli': 25.0}],
   ...: ['12319825', '39770', {'pH': 7.47, 'Escherichia coli': 27.0}],
   ...: ['12319825', '39967', {'pH': 8.36}], ['12319825', '39972', {'pH': 8.42}]
   ...: ,
   ...: ['12319825', '39987', {'pH': 8.12, 'Escherichia coli': 8.0}],
   ...: ['12319825', '40014', {'pH': 8.12}], ['12319825', '40329',{'pH': 8.45}],
   ...:
   ...: ['12319825', '40658', {'pH': 8.35, 'Escherichia coli': 6.3}],
   ...: ['12319825', '40686', {'pH': 8.17}],
   ...: ['12319825', '40714', {'pH': 8.13}], ['12319825', '40732', {'pH': 8.4}],
   ...:
   ...: ['12319825', '40809', {'pH': 8.42}],
   ...: ['12319825', '40827', {'pH': 8.46}],
   ...: ['12319825', '41043', {'pH': 8.42, 'Escherichia coli': 170.0}],
   ...: ['12319825', '41071', {'pH': 8.24, 'Escherichia coli': 92.0}],
   ...: ['12319825', '41080', {'pH': 8.4}],
   ...: ['12319825', '41101', {'pH': 8.36, 'Escherichia coli': 560.0}], ['123198
   ...: 25', '41134', {'pH': 8.67}]]
```

When your boolean conditions are even a little bit complex, you should given them their own functions, if only for the sake of readability. Here, I will go further and also add them to a dictionary, where the key is the corresponding pollutant, which will make your life very easy!

```
In [4]: def ecoli_threshold(value): return value > 320

In [5]: def ph_range(value): return not (5 < value < 9)

In [6]: test = {'Escherichia coli': ecoli_threshold, 'pH':ph_range}
```

And the key issue tripping you up is that you are using a *single list*, but you really need *two*. Initialize your dictionary with the two empty lists, since you know you will be appending to them.

```
In [7]: over_dict = {'Escherichia coli':[], 'pH':[]}
```

Finally, iterate over the data:

```
In [8]: for entry in data:
    ...:     for pollutant, value in entry[2].items():
    ...:         over_dict[pollutant].append((entry[1], test[pollutant](value)))
    ...:
```

And finally, the output:

```
In [9]: over_dict
Out[9]:
{'Escherichia coli': [('39638', False),
  ('39770', False),
  ('39987', False),
  ('40658', False),
  ('41043', False),
  ('41071', False),
  ('41101', True)],
 'pH': [('39274', False),
  ('39610', False),
  ('39638', False),
  ('39770', False),
  ('39967', False),
  ('39972', False),
  ('39987', False),
  ('40014', False),
  ('40329', False),
  ('40658', False),
  ('40686', False),
  ('40714', False),
  ('40732', False),
  ('40809', False),
  ('40827', False),
  ('41043', False),
  ('41071', False),
  ('41080', False),
  ('41101', False),
  ('41134', False)]}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback! The complicated thing is that there are many more pollutants this code will be looking at, and not all locations have each pollutant, so it will be hard to add lists by hand, but I think using these comments I can strategize an approach! Thanks!

Comment: @AmeliaMcClure then your best bet is to use a `defaultdict`, and it should be relatively straightforward to extend the rest of this approach above.